# Is there any true interpretation of the sentence $\forall x \forall y$ $((P(x) \wedge P(y)) \wedge (x \neq y))$

Tags: first-order-logic

This is the first sentence of a conditional I need to construct a false interpretation for. So I need to find an interpretation that makes this sentence true. However, it looks to me as if this can never be the case.

Since both variables $x, y$ are universally quantified, I would have to extend the predicate P to include all elements of the domain of the model in order to make the sentence $P(x) \wedge P(y)$ true.

So wouldn't there always be a case where $x = y$? I.E this sentence can never be true? Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're allowed to have an empty domain of discourse, then in such a model the statement would become (vacuously) true.

Comment: Do you mean $\land$ rather than $\cap$?

Comment: yes @RobertShore will edit

Comment: I think the domain must be non empty @DanielSchepler

Comment: @RobertShore, with only one element $x = y$ is *true*.

Comment: If empty domain is forbidden, then you're right, your statement implies $\forall x \forall y (x \ne y)$ which by specialization furthermore implies $\forall x (x \ne x)$, and that's equivalent to $\forall x, \bot$ which is equivalent to an empty domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain of discourse is not allowed to be empty, then the sentence is unsatisfiable for exactly the reason you gave, namely that (101) is false.

$$ \forall x \forall y . x \neq y \tag{101} $$

Let $c$ be an element of the domain. Pick $x = c$ and $y = c$ , now (101) is false. The further $P(x) \land$ and $P(y) \land$ do not affect the analysis because an expression headed by $\land$ is false if either of its arguments is false.

If the domain of discourse is allowed to be empty, then the sentence is vacuously true because the *outermost quantifier* is universal. All sentences of the form (102) (with $\varphi_x$ being an arbitrary sentence that potentially includes $x$) are true because there body of quantifier is never "evaluated" and doesn't get a chance to influence the truth value of the expression as a whole.

$$ \forall x . \varphi_x \tag{102}$$

Roughly speaking, if you think of (102) as a game, then the *opponent* makes a move and gets to pick an item from the domain. The domain is empty though, so the opponent can't move and therefore loses.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is nonempty, $\forall x\forall y$ includes the case when $x = y$, so...